# 'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler' replace with 'try catch and finally' block

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I have converted VB6 project to VB.NET(VS2005). After converted, i want to  replace 'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler' with try catch block. Please give me some examples of the below code to "try catch finally" block. Thank you.

```
Private Sub GetMktAccessRights2(ByRef jsonObj As Scripting.Dictionary, ByRef nCount As Short)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim i As Short
    Dim ctr As Short

    If nCount = 0 Then
        WriteErrorToTextFile(ErrorFileName, "Cannot get market access rights description.")
        InsertDealerErrorLog("FrmMain: GetMktAccessRights(): Cannot get market access rights description.")

        MsgBox("Cannot get market access rights description.", MsgBoxStyle.OKOnly)
    Else
        NumOfExch = 0
        For i = 1 To nCount
            'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object jsonObj.Item().Item. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
            If (AccessRights And jsonObj.Item("records").Item(i).Item("DealerRights")) = jsonObj.Item("records").Item(i).Item("DealerRights") Then
                NumOfExch = NumOfExch + 1
                'UPGRADE_WARNING: Couldn't resolve default property of object jsonObj.Item().Item. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6A50421D-15FE-4896-8A1B-2EC21E9037B2"'
                CFD_data(NumOfExch - 1).Market = Trim(jsonObj.Item("records").Item(i).Item("Market"))
            End If
        Next 
        If NumOfExch = 0 Then
            InsertDealerErrorLog("FrmMain: GetMktAccessRights(): You cannot access any of the markets.")
            MsgBox("You cannot access any of the markets because you are not assign access to the different markets.", MsgBoxStyle.OKOnly)
        End If
    End If

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: 
    MsgBox("GetMktAccessRights2 Error. Maybe response message error.")
    Resume Next

End Sub

Private Function SendDealerInfoToRskMng(ByVal Loginout As Boolean, ByVal DealerID As String, ByVal MarketList As String, ByVal ListidList As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    WriteErrorToTextFile(LogFileName, "Begin to SendDealerInfoToRskMng.")

    Dim logindata As DealerLoginData
    logindata = New DealerLoginData

    Dim strDate As String
    strDate = VB6.Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss")

    tcpendpoint.SendOut(logindata.handle)

    SendDealerInfoToRskMng = True

    'UPGRADE_NOTE: Object logindata may not be destroyed until it is garbage collected. Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="6E35BFF6-CD74-4B09-9689-3E1A43DF8969"'
    logindata = Nothing

    WriteErrorToTextFile(LogFileName, "Success to SendDealerInfoToRskMng.")
    Exit Function
ErrHandler: 
    MsgBox("PMEModule:SendDealerInfoToRskMng()->" & Err.Description)
    InsertDealerErrorLog("PMEModule:SendDealerInfoToRskMng()->" & Err.Description)
    End

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

All it takes is removing `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` and your GoTo itself; but don't remove the code after. Also, remove the `Exit Function`.

What you then can do is follow this format;

```
Try
    ' Your first code before ErrHandler:
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Anything in your ErrHandler and replace Err.Description with ex.Message
End Try
```

Comment: @Nightmare `Resume Next` doesn't work when you're using a Try Catch - so remove it. You should remove `Exit Sub`, too.

Comment: @Nightmare : Clarifying Alex's comment: `Resume Next` and `Exit Sub` _**isn't needed**_ in `Try/Catch`.

Comment: @VisualVincent while `Exit Sub` may not be needed, `Resume Next` won't actually *compile* when put in or above a `Try/Catch`...

Comment: Well no, of course. ;)

Comment: With all respect, this answer is leaving out important information. If you remove `Resume Next` you are changing the behaviour of the code. In VB6 and VB.Net [`Resume Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91k6c8b5.aspx) will return execution to the main body of the routine, at the line immediately after the line where the error occurred. There is no practical way to replicate this behaviour with a `Try-Catch` block.

Comment: ... It *may* be safe to remove the `Resume Next` statement, and cause the routines to abort if an error occurs, rather than keep on trying. It depends what they do (should `GetMktAccessRights2` keep on going round that `For - Next` loop?). IMHO you should leave the code alone (assuming this is tested, working VB6 code). Do you really have time to check the use of `Resume Next` carefully?

Comment: @MarkJ while it is doing so, the OP is asking for a `Try/Catch` replacement for `On Error`.

Comment: @Alex The OP posted code which includes Resume Next. There's **no exact replacement** for that code that uses Try Catch.

Comment: @MarkJ - `After converted, i want to replace 'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler' with try catch block.` Taken from the question.